# Add a Calculated Row to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to add a row into a data set that is derived from a calculation in the current dat set.  So, the DF will become longer as a result.  Further, the data needs to aggregate / group by other criteria, date, account etc.

I have the following original DF structure:

```
CC_SHORT <- c("1-101", "1-101","1-101", "1-101","1-102", "1-102","1-102", "1-102")
CC_FULL <- c("Line 101", "Line 101","Line 101", "Line 101","Line 102", "Line 102","Line 102", "Line 102")
ACC_SHORT <- c("230L", "231H","230L", "231H","230L", "231H","230L", "231H")
ACC_FULL <- c("230 low", "231 high","230 low", "231 high","230 low", "231 high","230 low", "231 high")
Date <-c ("04/01/2022","04/01/2022","05/01/2022","05/01/2022","04/01/2022","04/01/2022","05/01/2022","05/01/2022")
Value <- c(60,100,50,80,65,75,85,105)  
DF<-data.frame(CC_SHORT, CC_FULL,ACC_SHORT,ACC_FULL,Date,Value)
```

I am trying to add a the new row to column ACC SHORT, the new variable is named '23M' which is a calulation based on ACC SHORT variable '230' minus '231'.

The new DF should look like so:

```
CC_SHORT1 <- c("1-101", "1-101","1-101", "1-101","1-101", "1-101","1-102", "1-102","1-102", "1-102","1-102", "1-102")

CC_FULL1 <- c("Line 101", "Line 101","Line 101", "Line 101","Line 101", "Line 101","Line 102", "Line 102","Line 102", "Line 102","Line 102", "Line 102")

ACC_SHORT1 <- c("230", "231","23M", "230","231", "23M","230", "231","23M", "230","231", "23M")

ACC_FULL1 <- c("230 low", "231 high","23 MID","230 low", "231 high","23 MID","230 low", "231 high","23 MID","230 low", "231 high", "23 MID")

Date1 <-c ("04/01/2022","04/01/2022","04/01/2022","05/01/2022","05/01/2022","05/01/2022","04/01/2022","04/01/2022","04/01/2022","05/01/2022","05/01/2022","05/01/2022")

Value1 <- c(60,100,40,50,80,30,35,75,40,85,105,20)

DF1<-data.frame(CC_SHORT1, CC_FULL1,ACC_SHORT1,ACC_FULL1,Date1,Value1)
```

Been trying wiI have been using tidyr but cannot figure out the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

id <- DF %>%
  select(ACC_SHORT,ACC_FULL) %>%
  unique %>%
  rbind(data.frame(ACC_SHORT="23M",ACC_FULL="23 MID"))

DF %>% 
  select(-ACC_FULL) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from=Value,names_from= c(ACC_SHORT)) %>%
  mutate(`23M`=`231H`-`230L`) %>%
  pivot_longer(`230L`:`23M`,names_to='ACC_SHORT') %>%
  merge(id)

   ACC_SHORT CC_SHORT  CC_FULL       Date value ACC_FULL
1       230L    1-101 Line 101 04/01/2022    60  230 low
2       230L    1-102 Line 102 05/01/2022    85  230 low
3       230L    1-102 Line 102 04/01/2022    65  230 low
4       230L    1-101 Line 101 05/01/2022    50  230 low
5       231H    1-101 Line 101 05/01/2022    80 231 high
6       231H    1-101 Line 101 04/01/2022   100 231 high
7       231H    1-102 Line 102 05/01/2022   105 231 high
8       231H    1-102 Line 102 04/01/2022    75 231 high
9        23M    1-102 Line 102 04/01/2022    10   23 MID
10       23M    1-101 Line 101 05/01/2022    30   23 MID
11       23M    1-101 Line 101 04/01/2022    40   23 MID
12       23M    1-102 Line 102 05/01/2022    20   23 MID
```

Comment: This partially works.  However in the full dataset there are examples where there is no  230 entry for a particular period or line.  In this case I would require the calculation to give the 231 amount ('231' - 0) however the calculation returns blank data (meaning the overall dataset does not reconcile, as  '23M' does not equal total '231' - total '230' and '23M' calculation is incorrect in instances where there is no 230 data line).  I have spent the last couple of hours trying to resolve this but unable to.

Comment: I think the solution is to patch in zero to all the blank lines that are created before the calculation step but I am unable to adapt the code succeefully.....

Comment: change the mutate to ```mutate(`23M`=case_when(is.na(`230L`)~`231H`,
                       T~`231H`-`230L`))```